# How to post long JSON as a body using retrofit?

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit

I am using **retrofit** to handle the API calls but facing problem while posting long JSON. I am getting:

> internal server error(code : 500)

I need to convert post params to below format.

Body :

```
{"UserId" : "2",
"PortalId" : "1",
"LocaleId" : "1",
"CatalogId" : "3",
"Items" : [{"Name" : "ap1234","Quantity" : "1"}]}
```

Below is the code I am using 
Api Call :

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject1.put("Name", "ap1234");
            jsonObject1.put("Quantity", "1");
            array.put(jsonObject1);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Call data = mApiInterface.getData("application/json","2", "1", "1", "3", array.toString());
        addToCart.enqueue(new Callback<DataResponse>() {
```

Retrofit Interface :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(API_ADD_TO_CART)
    Call<DataResponse> getData(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Field("UserId") String userId,
                               @Field("LocaleId") String localeId,
                               @Field("PortalId") String portalId,
                               @Field("CatalogId") String CatalogId,
                               @Field("Items") String Items);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Body String body** has to be used.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject1.put("Name", "ap1234");
        jsonObject1.put("Quantity", "1");
/* 
 create a json object pass as body   
 {"UserId" : "2",
   "PortalId" : "1",
    "LocaleId" : "1", 
    "CatalogId" : "3",
    "Items" : [{"Name" : "ap1234","Quantity" : "1"}]}

       */
    array.put(jsonObject1);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  Call data = mApiInterface.getData("application/json","2", "1", "1", 
"3", array.toString());
    addToCart.enqueue(new Callback<DataResponse>() {
```

change as following

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(API_ADD_TO_CART)
Call<DataResponse> getData(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body String body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the @Body annotation .

Create a User class add your data to that instance and with retrofit instead of using @field you should send @Body with the User class as body .

example:

```
interface Foo {
  @POST("/jayson")
  FooResponse postRawJson(@Body TypedInput body);
}
```

For more info I found this link to be helpful 
[https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body](http://link)

Answer (score 0):

retrofit is too typical to implement and this is the easiest method I ever used for retrofit.

```
public void sendPost(String s1) {
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        apiService.getData(s1).enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    if (response != null) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                        String status = jsonObject.optString("status");

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                if (dialog != null) {
                    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't think **@Header("Content-Type") String contentType** is useful in api services, just use @Field to send request

```
@POST("list_data")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<JsonObject> shopList(@Field("string") String string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I did it using @Body

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys I did it using @Body

```
@POST(API_ADD_TO_CART)
Call<ShoppingCartResponse> getData(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body DataRequest request)


public class AddToCartRequest {

@SerializedName("UserId")
@Expose
private String userId;
@SerializedName("PortalId")
@Expose
private String portalId;
@SerializedName("LocaleId")
@Expose
private String localeId;
@SerializedName("CatalogId")
@Expose
private String catalogId;
@SerializedName("Items")
@Expose
private List<Items> items = null;

public String getUserId() {
return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
this.userId = userId;
}

public String getPortalId() {
return portalId;
}

public void setPortalId(String portalId) {
this.portalId = portalId;
}

public String getLocaleId() {
return localeId;
}

public void setLocaleId(String localeId) {
this.localeId = localeId;
}

public String getCatalogId() {
return catalogId;
}

public void setCatalogId(String catalogId) {
this.catalogId = catalogId;
}

public List<Item> getItems() {
return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
this.items = items;
}

}
```